# How can I determine which package my constructor was called from?

Tags: perl

I got a package called `1.pm` in that the constructor is calling a subroutine which is in the same package.

Now, if some other classes say `2.pm` is calling the constructor defined in `1.pm`, how can I determine if the subroutine is called from `2.pm`?

Comment: Out of interest, why does 1.pm need to know its calling package at construction time? It seems odd that the constructor's behaviour would be dependent on the package calling it.

Comment: Maybe for debug or profiling reasons?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) builtin:

```
$package = caller;
```

If you want more information you can use:

```
($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
```

See [perldoc -f caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).

Comment: or just `my $package = caller;`.

Comment: I am using it for Log info. 
Basically I am tracking all info using Log::Log4perl

Comment: @Nach: Log::Log4perl will automatically track that information for you if you configure it properly; there's no need to take special steps. (See the latest FAQ, on CPAN.)